# Provide string as dynamic function with inline changes

Tags: php

This currently works:

```
    $get_pending_list_action = "get_pending_list_".$action;
    $data = $this->sectorswaps->{$get_pending_list_action}($list);
```

Is there anyway to make it so I can turn this into one line?

i.e. this does NOT work:

```
    $data = $this->sectorswaps->get_pending_list_{$action}($list);
```

Is there some other way that I dont know of?

Comment: Is a one liner more important than readability?

Comment: did you try: `$data = $this->sectorswaps->{"get_pending_list_".$action}($list);`

Comment: @MattWhipple - thanks matt - its so obvious now. if you can post that as the answer - i'll accept

Comment: @MarkBaker: There is nothing wrong about learning new things..

Comment: @MarkBaker - to be honest - I find it easier to read on the one line, especially when I have 3-4 of these in a row

Comment: A one-liner might be easier for you to read when it's fresh in your mind, and you know what you're expecting.... doesn't necessarily make it easier for others to read and understand, or for you to remember it in 6 months time. There's nothing wrong with learning new things, but new isn't always better... more important to learn the how to code in a way that you and others can subsequently maintain with ease... if a one-liner is "better", then use it; but knowing when to use more than one line for readability is also a coding skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$data = $this->sectorswaps->{"get_pending_list_".$action}($list);`